# Why does my Perl script not do anything if I invoke with Popen immediately followed by wait or sleep from Python?

Tags: python, perl, subprocess, sleep, popen

I am invoking a Perl script with Popen.  The following code works:

```
command = "ldapadder " + filename  
args = shlex.split(command)
with open(os.devnull, 'w') as proc:
   popen_result = Popen(args, stdout=proc)
```

"ldapadder" is an **executable** Perl script.  (Yes, I am aware of the LDAP module for Python, and it's not an option for us right now)

However, if I attempt to use Popen.wait(), Popen.communicate(), or even time.sleep() immediately after the Popen call, the Perl script doesn't execute.  For example:

```
command = "ldapadder " + filename  
args = shlex.split(command)
with open(os.devnull, 'w') as proc:
   popen_result = Popen(args, stdout=proc)
time.sleep(5)
```

The above code takes no action --- the Perl script isn't executed, and even if I print stderr and stdout of the Popen via PIPE, the contents are empty/blank.  Did the same thing without the os.devnull as well to insure I would get output, but nothing happens at all.

I've tried at least 10 other variations of this, including:

```
command = "ldapadder " + filename  
args = shlex.split(command)
popen_result = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = popen_result.communicate()
print stdout;
print stderr;
```

and:

```
command = "ldapadder " + filename  
args = shlex.split(command)
popen_result = Popen(args)
popen_result.wait()
```

With the above two snippets as well, nothing happens.  The Perl script does not appear to execute at all.  I'm unsure of how I can get any more information about what is going wrong, considering that the execution of the Perl script does not output standard output or errors when called by a Popen followed by a wait.  To clarify, the Perl script does indeed throw out messages and errors when run independently.

This is Python 2.6, and I already tried the same type of variations with subprocess.call() --- same thing.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. If you do *not* specify `stdout` or `stderr` it's *correct* that you don't see anything. However when *I* use `stdout=PIPE` I **do** see the output.

Comment: Well that may be where the weirdness comes in.  Even if I don't specify stdout or stderr, i.e. "Popen(args)", it executes but I see output anyway.

Comment: @Bakuriu: you've got it backwards. If you do *not* specify `stdout`, `stderr` then they are inherited from the parent i.e., you should see both if you run the Python script in a terminal. If you set `stdout=PIPE` then you may or may not see the output depending on where subprocess writes (if it writes to stdout then you won't see it but you can read it using `.communicate()` or `.stdout` file object directly. If it writes directly to the terminal then you should see it but you won't read it via `.communicate()` or `.stdout`).

Comment: What the script should do? Does it write files? What is your OS?

Comment: RHEL6, and the Perl script adds a record to an LDAP database --- it does not write any files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Popen()` starts new subprocess. If it returns; the process is already started. Check that you do not ignore exceptions silently in your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
import subprocess

# log to a file in case `ldapadder` corrupts terminal
logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)-15s %(message)s", datefmt="%F %T",
                    filename='logfile', level=logging.DEBUG)
p = logging.getLogger(__name__).info

p("before ldapadder")
try:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["ldapadder", filename], close_fds=True)
    p("after Popen")
    proc.wait()
    p("after wait")
finally:
    p("after ldappedder")
```

Run it:

```
$ python2.6 the_script.py
```

And check `logfile`. You can do it while `the_script.py` is still running.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Copy/paste, the code will ONLY work when proc.wait() is commented out.  If proc.wait() is uncommented, ldapadder is never executed.  In either case, the logfile has all four lines, and there are no other error messages.  The existence of proc.wait() is the single and only thing that is causing ldapadder to not execute (which was the same symptom I had with other wait methods, including time.sleep())

Comment: @CptSupermrkt: *"ldapadder is never executed"* is incorrect. If you see all 4 lines then it means that `ldapadder` is started, executed (there is literally `exec*` call on Unix) and ended. Check `proc.returncode` to see whether it reports any errors. Does it do what you want it to do if you replace `proc.wait()` by `while proc.poll() is None: pass` or even `while True: pass`?

Comment: Negative on both proc.poll and while True.  The return code is 0 under all circumstances (no wait, wait, poll, and while true).

Comment: @CptSupermrkt: Does it work if you add `time.sleep(0)`, execute the script several times, refresh ldap database view, flush buffers?Please, [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20405698/4279) and include the *complete, minimal* code example and the actual command that you used to run it. Include info on how do you check that ldap database is updated. Does `ldapadder` works if you put the command in a bash script, add `sleep` command?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.  I'm just throwing my hands up at this one.  I'm thinking more and more that it's a problem or issue with the Perl script.  The Perl script isn't actually mine, sort of an internal black box that I can't modify or experiment with.